# Interactive 'TAGS/PROP/TODO' query limited to particular level of tree?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, interactive, org-tags

I want to do a search where I interactively specify a tag (ideally with `counsel-org-tag`-style tag completion) and get an agenda buffer listing matching items at a particular level of the hierarchy (level 2).

For example, with this tree:

```
* spam
** onions :yes:
** artichokes :no:
* eggs :yes:
* ham
** gruyere :yes:
*** raspberries :yes:
```

I want run some command which prompts me for a tag (ideally using `counsel-org-tag`).  Say I enter the tag `yes`.  Then I would like to see the following headings listed in the agenda:

```
onions
gruyere
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Which of your requirements is not covered by org-agenda [tag matching](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties)?

Comment: @Juancho I don't want to have to specify the tree depth every time -- I want a view that encodes the tree level specification, so that interactively I only need to provide the tag.  If there's a way to do that without elisp (beyond simple configuration), I don't know what it is.  In fact it's not obvious to me how to do that with elisp either -- I kind of suspect it would involve writing more code than I'd like, hence this question :-)